# Link cURL lib but no lib files in cURL directory

Tags: c++, curl, linker, libcurl

*(I know this question has been asked many times, but I seem to have a special case)*

I am using gcc (version info below) to compile a C++ program that scrapes a hard-coded url using libcURL. I am running this on a Windows 10.

```
> gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\Windows\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/windows/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

All the libcURL packages that I found had a dll file to be compiled with. However, I didn't want to use that dll because all the examples on the net used header files and I wanted this to be a standalone executable. So I ended up downloading the source files (download wizard link: https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=source&os=-)

When I compiled my file, I ended up with the undefined reference error. I had gotten this error before when I didn't link the right .lib files. Except this time, there were no lib files anywhere in the cURL directory. Some other SO questions said to link using -lcurl, but there were no curl.lib anywhere.

Do I need to get a new package? Or do I need to install libcURL? Or something else?

Code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include "curl-7.58.0\include\curl\curl.h"

std::string gout;

size_t write_data(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *usrd){
  gout += buffer;
  return size*nmemb;
}

int geturl(const char* url, std::string out){
  gout = "";
  out = "";
  CURL* hcurl = curl_easy_init();
  if(hcurl) {
    CURLcode res;
    curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_URL, (char*)url);
    curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    res = curl_easy_perform(hcurl);
    if(res != 0){
      curl_easy_cleanup(hcurl);
      return -1;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(hcurl);
    return 0;
  }else{
    curl_easy_cleanup(hcurl);
    return -1;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main(){return 0;}
```

When compiled with gcc results in the error message:

```
> gcc ./file.cpp -o ./test.exe
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6XcEeS.o:checkit-proto.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You don't actually *link* with the cURL library. Considering that it's in a custom location it seems you downloaded it yourself? Then, did you even *build it*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't build it. I searched for curl.h and included it.

Comment: `g++` maybe, mingw-gcc probably cant find c++ headers

Comment: Thatä's why you could not find any library files. If you donwloaded the source only, then you need to configure and build it. cURL is not a header-only library.

Comment: @ricco19 g++ has the same errors.

Comment: yeah, as mentioned, you need the library, not just a header file

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How would I build it?

Comment: @forthe https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Comment: @DrewDormann It seems to be working. Still compiling.

Comment: @DrewDormann It still throws the errors for the libcURL methods, but not the `std::__cxx11::basic_string` methods.

Comment: @forthe https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using/

Comment: @forthe you may need to find a tutorial on using libraries.  If you used the gcc command you posted in your original question, you have omitted your curl library.